# Clicking on Same button to Reverse Javascript effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

So I am very very new to JavaScript and unfortunately I don't know the basics too well also.

I was working on a code to make an element hidden after clicking it and again reversing back the effect by clicking the same button but I am unable to do so. Please help me here is the code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#boxclose').click(function(){
        $('#md-share-window').animate({'bottom':'-90px'},500,function(){});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a class to identify the state of the element you are animating.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/FgDaq/

```
$('#boxclose').click(function() {
    var c = 'on',
        el = '#md-share-window',
        duration = 500;

    if ($(el).hasClass(c)) {
        $(el).animate({'bottom': 0}, duration)
            .removeClass(c);
    } else {
        $(el).animate({'bottom': '-90px'}, duration)
            .addClass(c);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can I please know why duration = 500; was added ??

Comment: @user2414789 just as a good practice. Makes the code more maintainable and less prone to human-errors. If you ever want to change the animation durration, you have to change it only at one place.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to get the initial position (or hard code it) and keep track of whether you are in the initial or updated position:

```
$(function() {
    var shareWindow = $('#md-share-window');
    var initialPosition = shareWindow.css('bottom'); //get initial position
    var atInitialPos = true; //whether this is the initial or updated position

    $('#boxclose').on('click', function(){
        var newPosition = atInitialPos ? '-90px' : initialPosition; //determines new position
        shareWindow.animate({'bottom': newPosition}, 500);
        atInitialPos = !atInitialPos; //toggle initial position boolean
    });
});
```